# ASP.NET Jquery functions combine into one, if possible

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and JQuery.

Currently, I have the codes for JQuery to load two different pages and passing value based on two different buttons click (controling by button ID). It seems like I am duplicating the codes, so I wonder if I can make this some sort like javascript function to pass 4 parameters (Page or URL, RecordID, width, height). Lets me explain with the codes.

I have these two buttons:

```
<table width="80%" align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td width="45%"></td>
        <td width="10%" class="PageTitle"></td>
        <td width="45%" style="text-align:right;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="buttonCreateApprovedMDF" ID="buttonCreateApprovedMDF" 
            Text="Create Approved MDF" href="ApprovedCreateNew.aspx?AnotherID=" title="Create Approved MDF" class="button3"/>  
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="buttonCreateNote" ID="buttonCreateNote" 
            Text="Create Note" href="ProposalCreateNote.aspx?ProposalID=" title="Create Note" class="button3"/>           
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the JQuery codes (duplicated), just the Page and RecordID are different, everything is the same.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#<%= buttonCreateNote.ClientID %>').live('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var lblID = $("[ID$='ProposalID']").text();
    var page = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("ProposalCreateNote.aspx")%>' + '?ProposalID=' + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="ProposalID"]').text());
    var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title"); 
    //alert(page); 
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>') 
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>') 
    .dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true, 
        height: 650, 
        width: 900, 
        title: pagetitle 
    }); 
    $dialog.dialog('open'); 
    });

    $('#<%= buttonCreateApprovedMDF.ClientID %>').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lblID = $("[ID$='AnotherID']").text();
        var page = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("ApprovedCreateNew.aspx")%>' + '?AnotherID=' + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="AnotherID"]').text());
    var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title");
        //alert(page); 
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 650,
        width: 900,
        title: pagetitle
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

These the Labels (in the DetailsView) where the JQuery use for passing the parameters.

```
<asp:Label ID="ProposalID" runat="Server" style="text-align:left;" 
Text='<%# Eval("ProposedID")%>' />
<asp:Label ID="AnotherID" runat="Server" style="text-align:left;" 
Text='<%# Eval("AnotherID")%>' />
```

How can I combine the duplicated JQuery above into one function like "OpenIframe(URL, RecordID, Width, Height)"? and possibly using OnClientClick (with those parameters) to trigger IFrame popup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function OpenIframe(url, recordId, width, height, event)
{
    if(event.preventDefault)
        event.preventDefault(); 
    else
        event.returnValue = false;

    var page = url + "?" + recordId + "="+ encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="' + recordId + '"]').text());
    var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title"); 
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>') 
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>') 
    .dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true, 
        height: height | 650 , 
        width: width | 900, 
        title: pagetitle 
    }); 
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Your aspx would look like this:

```
<table width="80%" align="center" >
     <tr>
        <td width="45%"></td>
        <td width="10%" class="PageTitle"></td>
        <td width="45%" style="text-align:right;">
            <input type="button" onclick="OpenIframe('<%= ResolveClientUrl("ProposalCreateNote.aspx")%>', 'ProposalID', 900, 650, event); return false;" value="Create Approved MDF" title="Create Approved MDF" class="button3" />
            <input type="button" onclick="OpenIframe('<%= ResolveClientUrl("ApprovedCreateNew.aspx")%>', 'AnotherID', 900, 650, event); return false;" value="Create Note" title="Create Note" class="button3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Didn't use asp.net button markup because you would have to define it as runat="server" and you wouldn't be able to put escape characters on the OnClientClick event call.

Comment: Additionally, i noticed the variable "lblID" isn't used. You may take it off if it has no use. I took it off in the answer.

Comment: Sad thing is only works with Firefox, but not IE. not sure why, error "Object doesn't support this property or method", but I don't know where it failed. :(

Comment: Updated the answer, i think its because of the event object.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, but you updated codes works perfect for IE. BTW, what is the | symbol means "height: height | 650"? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: The expression "height | 650" returns the "height" variable value if it has value or the value 650 if it isn't. Meaning that if you call the OpenIframe function passing null to the height and width parameters, it will assume the values 650 and 900 respectively by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could include multiple selectors in a single query, separated by commas: e.g. `$('#foo, #bar')`. So, you could combine those two methods like following:

```
$('#<%= buttonCreateNote.ClientID %>, #<%= buttonCreateApprovedMDF.ClientID %>').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).id === '<%= buttonCreateApprovedMDF.ClientID %>') {
        var lblID = $("[ID$='AnotherID']").text();
        var page = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("ApprovedCreateNew.aspx")%>' + '?AnotherID=' + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="AnotherID"]').text());
    } else if ($(this).id === '<%= buttonCreateNote.ClientID %>') {
        var lblID = $("[ID$='ProposalID']").text();
        var page = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("ProposalCreateNote.aspx")%>' + '?ProposalID=' + encodeURIComponent($('span[id$="ProposalID"]').text());
    } else {
        return;
    }
    var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title");
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"  frameBorder="0"  align="middle"> ></iframe>').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 650,
        width: 900,
        title: pagetitle
    });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me another method (include multiple selectors). I will try this method later.